# Random enemy position and type spawn from an array not updating properly with each button click

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, random

I need my spawnEnemyClick button to spawn a new enemy in 1 of 3 random positions (which it does) and the spawned enemy should be 1 random enemy from the 5 enemy types in an array (which it doesn't do). The enemy type from the array will change if I close the swf and re-open it, but not on spawnEnemyClick. I've tried moving the enemy variable(s) into the spawnEnemyClick function in different ways, which is how I fixed the random position spawning, but it will not work due to all of the enemy variables. Also, if there is a better way to have a random enemy type array that doesn't use multiple variables, I'd be interested in that too.

```
 package 
    {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;

        public class Main_EnemySpawnTest_2 extends MovieClip
        {
            // variables
            var enemyType:Array = [Enemy1, Enemy2, Enemy3, Enemy4, Enemy5];
            var enemyTypeRandomNumber:int = Math.random() * (enemyType.length);
            var enemy = new enemyType[enemyTypeRandomNumber];
            var topPosition:uint = 100;
            var centerPosition:uint = 300;
            var bottomPosition:uint = 500;
            var enemySpeed:int = 5;

            public function Main_EnemySpawnTest_2 ():void
            {
                // listeners
                addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, checkEveryFrame);
                spawnEnemyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnEnemyClick);
                spawnEnemyButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnEnemyClick);
            }

            public function checkEveryFrame(event:Event):void
            {
                // enemy speed
                enemy.x = enemy.x - enemySpeed;
            }

            function spawnEnemyClick (event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var enemyPositionRandomNumber:int = Math.random() * 3; 
                var enemyPositionX:int = stage.width - (enemy.width * -0.5);
                if (enemyPositionRandomNumber == 0)
                {
                    enemy.x = enemyPositionX;
                    enemy.y = topPosition;
                    addChild (enemy);
                }
                else if (enemyPositionRandomNumber == 1)
                {
                    enemy.x = enemyPositionX;
                    enemy.y = centerPosition;
                    addChild (enemy);
                }
                else if (enemyPositionRandomNumber == 2)
                {
                    enemy.x = enemyPositionX;
                    enemy.y = bottomPosition;
                    addChild (enemy);
                }
                trace (enemyTypeRandomNumber);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random number is only created once in the constructor here:

```
var enemyTypeRandomNumber:int = Math.random() * (enemyType.length);
```

You are working with the same enemy object again and again.
To fix this, move the random enemy creation into `spawnEnemyClick` function, so "throws the dice again and again" just like you do with the position now.

hint: removing and re-adding the listener in that function is pointless. It will always finish executing the function. this is not an interrupt or parallel or whatever else makes you think that you need to disable the listener during the function.

Edit:
You receive the errors because the variables are not properly defined.
Keep the lines as they are and reassign value to enemy in `spawnEnemyClick` function.

```
enemy = new enemyType[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemyType.length)];
```

Something like that. Without "var", because you do not want to reassign the value.

Comment: I fixed the add/remove listener, but I can't move any of the 3 enemy variables into the function, or the code doesn't work. I've already tried every combination of moving them before and again after updating the add/remove listener.

Comment: @crabdog62482 saying that it doesn't work is not helpful at all. Post one of your attempts in the question and explain what errors your got.

Comment: If I move any of the enemy variables to enemySpawnClick, I receive the same error on multiple lines: 1120: Access of undefined property “variable name".

Comment: I still need help with this problem. I've been trying things for the last week and a half, but I'm not making any progress.

Comment: @crabdog62482 I added something to my answer, does that help?

Comment: Thank you so much. That works. Although now, each time I click the spawn enemy button it spawns a new enemy of a random type, while stopping the old enemy and leaving it on screen. I might be able to figure this out when I get some time later, but any ideas on this?

Comment: @crabdog62482 the enemy variable can only hold one object, you need an array instead that can hold many objects. If you cannot figure it out, try finding question related to that or ask a question yourself.